# Dont understand this Trailing Closure

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm New to swift here. Was reading closures on weheartswift. There is one section talking about trailing closure. Three questions here:

1. I think there is some typo in the code: shouldn't function just be func?
2. I think the 3 lines code in { } are just the trailing closure for f:(Int) -> (Int), but what does f(i) in that 3 lines code means?
3. When I try to run this code in playground, it gives me this error on the line: "return sum" Unexpected non-void return value in void function.

Code:

```
function sum(from: Int, to: Int, f: (Int) -> (Int)) {    

    var sum = 0
    for i in from...to {    
    sum += f(i)
    }
    return sum
}

sum(1, 10) {    

     $0    
} // the sum of the first 10 numbers 

sum(1, 10) {

    $0 * $0
} // the sum of the first 10 squares
```

Comment: thanks Dharmesh for update my format again, I really need to make it right next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your working code:

```
func sum(from: Int, to: Int, f: (Int) -> (Int)) -> Int{
    var sum = 0
    for i in from...to {
        sum += f(i)
    }
    return sum
}

sum(1, to: 10) {
    $0
} // the sum of the first 10 numbers

sum(1, to: 10) {
    $0 * $0
} // the sum of the first 10 squares
```

As per your error it says that you are declaring a function which doesn't have any return value but you return `Int` at the end with `return sum`. so change your function syntax as shown into above code by adding `-> Int` which says that function will return an `Int` and it will work fine.

Comment: So, what does f ( i ) mean here? Is f another small closure? which take "i" as input and return another "int", but by how?

Comment: As you declare into your function syntax at start it is a closure with type `(Int) -> (Int)`  which take `i` as input and return another `Int`. and that `Int` will add into `sum` instance.

Comment: So, where is the Statement for this small f ( Int ) -> ( Int ) closure? Without statement we just assume it takes input as output?

Comment: Replace `f(i)` with `i` and check the result.

Comment: I see, I always think that we need these format for statement "{ ( parameters ) in statements } " Looks like it can be further simplified. Your comment is heuristic